# How to use the value of a key, inside the other key of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

The question seems confusing, so let me explain:

I was working with this snippet of code:

```
sy: 100,
sx: 50,

x: 30,
y: height - this.sy,
```

I used 'y' in a function but the function did not seem to work, so I did alert(y); which gave told me that the value of 'v' was 'NaN'. Then I tested 'y' using the typeof operator which told me it was of the type 'number'. I know that a number can be of the type 'number' and still not be a number, so I realized the problem was in the 'this.sy' part. I think 'this' is only used for function, so how would I go about accessing 'sy' while still inside the array? (height is already defined outside of the array)

Comment: Any piece of code that uses `this` MUST show more context around the code than you are for us to know what the value of `this` is set to.  Also, it isn't clear whether you realize that `y` will be computed once when the code is initialized and will not be a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:  Please see the getter answer above, that allows the syntax to resemble a property while still retaining the implementation as a function.  One thing to note that the getter is read only, so if you do obj.y = 4, that won't change the value.  It could be considered a downside of this, that it may lead users to believe it can be changed.  Details, including which browsers have support, are here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Original Answer:
you need to make y a function:

```
var obj = {
...
y : function () {
    return this.height - this.sy;
},
...
}
```

alert(obj.y());

I'm assuming that the height was a property you've already defined.

Comment: Then you cannot access it with "obj.y". You have to access it with "obj.y()"...!

Comment: yes I'v posted that in the example usage.  But regardless, I think a getter is a better solution.

Comment: You can make y settable if you want. Check my answer.

Comment: yes thanks for mentioning that.  My point was that using the getter alone could be a possible source of confusion.  If a property is read-only, then using a getter instead of an explicit function could mask the read-only nature of the property to users of the object unfamiliar with its semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getter:

```
var o = {sy: 100,
         sx: 50,

         x: 30,
         get y() { return height - this.sy },
         };
```

Later you can use it as a normal property:

```
height = 10;
o.y //gives -90
```

You cant use this outside a function since outside the function its just a global object. So in your case the value of `this.sy` is `undefined` and `100-undefined` is `NaN`.

You can even make `y` settable by defining setter:

```
var o = {sy: 100,
             sx: 50,

             x: 30,
             get y() { return height - this.sy },
             set y(val) {Object.defineProperty(this, 'y', {value: val})},
             };
```